# django concrete inheritance, __str__(self) in parent fails to pick attribute from child

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, django-admin

In Django, I am using concrete inheritance as follows:

The Client class is a concrete parent, having the common fields. A client can be an Individual, or a Partnership, or a Company...

***Note: Yes I have read up on disadvantages of concrete inheritance, but my database is going to be small, and I want to be able to enforce uniqueness constraints from the Client table easily.***

An objects name attribute resides in the child table only (Because an indiviual has FirstName, MiddleName, LastName whereas a Company does not)

I want to use the **str**(self) method from the Parent class to return the name of the Individual, Partnership or Company, as the case may be.

In the Individual Model, I have the name(self) method:

```
    def name(self):
        if self.Middle_Name is None:
            return self.First_Name + " " + self.Last_Name
        else:
            return self.First_Name + " " + self.Middle_Name + " " + self.Last_Name
```

In the Client() Model, I have the **str**(self) method:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name()
```

Understandably, I get the ***'Client' object has no attribute 'name'*** error when I have to get a list of all the client names.

Is there a way to make this work? I'm sorry, I'm very new to object oriented programming concepts and to Django.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way round. If your method is referencing an attribute that only exists on the child model, then it should be on that child model. As a bonus, that makes the logic a lot simpler:

```
class Client:
    def name(self):
        return self.First_Name + " " + self.Last_Name

class Individual(Client):
    def name(self):
        return self.First_Name + " " + self.Middle_Name + " " + self.Last_Name
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to use the __str__(self) method in the parent class, for django admin to be able to list all clients, irrespective of differences in their naming rules. __str__(self) method. I hope I am making sense. Thanks

Comment: That has nothing at all to do with this code. In the Django admin, if you look at the list page for Individuals, *all* instances will be Individuals, even if they are also Clients. So *none* of them will have Middle_Name attributes.

Comment: Just one more question, what did you mean by "class Client(Individual):", because it is individual which inherits from Client, not the other way round.